# Spark Streaming with Actor Never Terminates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Using Spark 1.5 Streaming with an Actor receiver.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[4]")
    .setAppName("ModelTest")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))

val models = ssc.actorStream[Model](Props(...), "ModelReceiver")

models.foreachRDD { rdd => ... }

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
// NEVER GETS HERE!
```

When the generated Actor is shutdown the code will not progress beyond `ssc.awaitTermination()`

If I kill SBT with `Ctrl+C` a `println` after the `ssc.awaitTermination()` line will complete.

How should Spark be terminated?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that Spark Streaming will await termination, as the function name hints.  To kill a Streaming application you send a SIGTERM to that process, for example by using the kill command.

As you can also see in the [Spark Standalone documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#launching-spark-applications) you can also kill the process using Spark Submit:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master url> <driver ID>
```

You can define some code that you want to run when the process is shutting down, by calling `sys.ShutdownHookThread`.

```
sys.ShutdownHookThread {
  log.info("Stopping Spark Streaming...")
  ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
  log.info("Shutting down the application...")
}
```

Comment: I apologize if i'm missing something obvious, but I don't see how this answers my question - how do I exit awaitTermination()?

Comment: You terminate the process, either as you are doing with CTRL-C, using kill and SIGTERM or using "spark-class ... kill".  And then the process will finish.