# Spark (Kafka) Streaming Memory Issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, out-of-memory

I am testing my first `Spark Streaming` pipline which processes messages from `Kafka`. However, after several testing runs, I got the following error message
`There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.`

My testing data is really small thus this should not happen. After looking into the `process`, I realized maybe previously submitted spark jobs were not removed completely? [image]

I usually submit jobs like below, and I am using `Spark 2.2.1`
`/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 ~/script/to/spark_streaming.py`

And stop it using `Ctrl+C'

Last few lines of the script looks like:

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

#### Update

After I changing the way to submit a spark streaming job (command like below), I still ran into same issue which is after killing the job, memory will not be released.I only started `Hadoop` and `Spark` for those 4 EC2 nodes.

```
/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 --py-files ~/config.py --master spark://<master_IP>:7077 --deploy-mode client  ~/spark_kafka.py
```

Answer (score 2):

When you press Ctrl-C, only the submitter process is interrupted, the job itself continues to run. Eventually your system runs out of memory so no new JVM can be started.

Furthermore, even if you restart the cluster, all previously running jobs will be restarted again.

Read [how to stop a running Spark application properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093959/stopping-a-running-spark-application).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried both methods `/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master URL:7077> <worker-ID>` and sending post request to `"<master url>:6066/v1/submissions/kill/<worker-ID>"`. However, both ways failed to release memory... Maybe because I used to wrong command to start a spark job using a cluster? This is what I used `/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 ~/script/to/spark_streaming.py`

Comment: How do you know that memory isn't released? Did the commands succeed? Make sure there is nothing running: "`curl http://localhost:6066/json`" and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495623/how-to-get-all-jobs-status-through-spark-rest-api). Also see [Spark REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).

Comment: I looked at `htop` and sort by memory usage to determine whether or not those spark processes have been killed. I restarted my cluster (on EC2) and those processes are gone... Maybe all of those are because I did not submit job correctly? I usually submit job on my master node. That means I should use `client mode`? or you suggest to submit through REST API?

Comment: @TH339 please describe your procedure how do run the app. My first suggestion is to check how the app works locally (Spark Master `local[*]`)

Comment: @wind, I ran the job on an EC2 cluster with 1 master and 3 workers.

Comment: @rustyx, acturally I still ran into the same issue. Please see the update above. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @TH339 let's try `/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 --py-files ~/config.py --master local[*] --deploy-mode client  ~/spark_kafka.py`

Comment: @wind, thanks for the suggestion but `--master local[*]` only runs locally, right? mine setup is a 4-node EC2 cluster

Comment: It's only to check if the process works the same in a single-JVM environment.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the problem of bunch of driver (spark-app-driver process) processes running on the host you use to submit spark job. Try doing something like

```
ps aux --forest
```

or similar depending on your platform to understand what are the processes running at the moment. Or you can have a look at answers over the stackoverflow [Spark Streaming with Actor Never Terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810478/spark-streaming-with-actor-never-terminates) , it might give you a glue on what is happening.